# Decoding date time format

Tags: datetime, http-headers

I need to be able to pass a similar `GET` request to an application that has no documentation and all i can see from Fiddler is the following date formats which make no sense.

Seeing that the application only supports Internet Explorer the same `GET` string using Google returns an XML response.

**String as seen in Fiddler**

```
Archive.cgi?cmd=query&ca=255&start_time=1400284860&end_time=1400371140&dst=2&level=0&username=QWRtaW4=&rnd=3940
```

**The same request response when using Google Chrome**

```
<Archive_Query>
<result>1</result>
<Size>9806</Size>
<st>0x5376a5ea</st>
<et>0x53775c9f</et>
<Stream_num>1</Stream_num>
</Archive_Query
```

As i need to be able to pass dates and time in the format YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM am/pm,i need to be able to decode the date formatting so that i can pass it in the appropriate format. It appears to be using the script from http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date looks to be a Unix timestamp or what is also called and epoch date. If you are using javascript you can format the date using moment.js. Ex. moment.unix(1318781876).

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks. Is there a site that would allow me to decode the date time stamps in the query string so that i can ascertain if it returns the value i'm expecting?

Comment: Here is a site that will convert the timestamp to a date/time for you. http://www.epochconverter.com/